# How to convert an array of numpy.float64 into an array of float64?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a np.array containing several other np.arrays, themselves containing objects of type numpy.float64, which cause the following issue with one of my methods:

```
TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.
```

The error is on this line of my code specifically:

```
self.x = torch.from_numpy(X_train)[train]
```

Is there a way to convert the content of a np.array to a regular type instead of a numpy object?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There is `ndarray.tolist()` which converts the array to ordinary (nested) lists.

Comment: maybe use list comprehension, something like x = [list(i) for i in lst]

Comment: What do you run that raises the error ?

Comment: I'm trying to run this specific line : self.x = torch.from_numpy(X_train)[train], but the content of my X_train contains numpy.float64 instead of regular 64, hence the issue

Comment: @MVMV If I put that into my python, I get `name X_train is not defined`. Again, please do create a proper [mcve]. I.e. code I can copy-paste and see the same error you get. How can we help you if we cannot see what the issue really is.

Comment: It is normal for a `numpy.array` to contain `numpy.float64`, the fact you get `numpy.object_` means there is some numpy array NOT containing the correct types.

Comment: @Quimby yes, sorry about that, you can use this example : X_train = np.array([[7.7000000e+01, 1.0000000e+02], [3.5294120e-02, 1.0000000e+00]])

Comment: @Quimby ok thanks, I will try to check in the array if there is some issue

Comment: Using this variable generates no errors, can you please print `X_train.dtype`? In my case it is `float64`. What about `train`? What is its `dtype`? Torch will generate the error above if the dtype is `object`.

Comment: @Quimby yes, train has been created through the line " for train, val in skf.split(X_train,y_train): ", as for the content of train and X_train, here is the result of print(np.shape(train), type(train), train.dtype) and print(np.shape(X_train), type(X_train), X_train.dtype) : TRAIN: (11880,) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> int64
X_TRAIN: (13201,) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> object. So as you said, it seems there is a problem with an element of X_train, though I still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I investigated and it is a problem of dimension of one of the elements of my array. Thanks for your answers everyone.

Comment: Glad you have found out what was causing that :)